# How to draw a dynamic height line in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I wanted to draw a dynamic height line, as shown in the given picture below
[image: as shown here, grey line]

I did something line this using a continer with one sided border

```
Container(
child:(content goes here....)
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:16+20.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            left: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade600),

                      ),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
)
```

but the issue is the corners(top and below) of the line is not rounded.

I want to draw a vertical line on the left side of my post, and on the right side goes the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 5,
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
          color: const Color(0x7f9e9e9e),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(child: **content goes here**),
    ],
  ),
)
```

And here's a DartPad example for you: [Example](https://dartpad.dev/82fa923533b8dd3c35eac6c7c9a0a867)

Which will produce something like this:

[image]

Where the bar on the left will size automatically with the contents on the right.